# Database monitoring tool for id overflow

Tags: sql, database, consistency

It can happen that amount in data of application will grow non-linearly, for example because amount of users grows and each user performs certain number of transactions each day.

In this case there is a danger to overlook some ID columns overflow in database (we may suppose that records from table are archived so there will not be really 2 billions records for int id overflow).

I'm curious to know whether there exists some tool for checking (for example, nightly) whether some IDs are close to their data type limit (and perhaps for other technical troubles).

Comment: Creating a script to do this should not be difficult.

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm interesting whether such tools exist in abundance or all people are always writing them themselves.

Comment: There probably is, on your on maybe you could set a trigger and possible send an email when id reaches dangerous value.